# In CSS, can HSL values be floats?

Tags: css, hsl

The [CSS3 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#hsla-color) only specifies that:

> The format of an HSLA color value in the functional notation is ‘hsla(’ followed by the hue in degrees, saturation and lightness as a percentage, and an , followed by ‘)’.

So am I to understand that these values would be interpreted not as integers but as floats? Example:

`hsla(200.2, 90.5%, 10.2%, .2)`

That would dramatically expand the otherwise small (relative to RGB) range of colors covered by HSL.

It seems to render fine in Chrome, though I don't know if they simply parse it as an INT value or what.

Comment: Different browsers handle them differently. Try making an example.

Answer (score 5):

HSL values are converted to hexadecimal RGB values before they are handed off to the system. It's up to the device to clip any resulting RGB value that is outside the "device gamut" - the range of colors that can be displayed - to a displayable value. RGB values are denoted in Hexadecimal. This is the specified algorithm for browsers to convert HSL values to RGB values. Rounding behavior is not specified by the standard - and there are multiple ways of doing rounding since there doesn't appear to be a built-in rounding function in either C or C++.

```
HOW TO RETURN hsl.to.rgb(h, s, l): 
       SELECT: 
      l<=0.5: PUT l*(s+1) IN m2
      ELSE: PUT l+s-l*s IN m2
       PUT l*2-m2 IN m1
       PUT hue.to.rgb(m1, m2, h+1/3) IN r
       PUT hue.to.rgb(m1, m2, h    ) IN g
       PUT hue.to.rgb(m1, m2, h-1/3) IN b
       RETURN (r, g, b)
```

From [the proposed recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#hsl-color)

In other words, you should be able to represent the exact same range of colors in HSLA as you can represent in RGB using fractional values for HSLA.

Comment: Without an explicit color profile, don't all devices map the RGB value range (e.g. `0` to `255`) to the full range of possible LCD or electron gun output level (e.g. fully-opaque or off to fully-transparent or on), after display RGB factory-balancing and gamma correction (affecting the middle of the range, not the end-points)?  And since CSS `hsl()` and `rgb()` colors don't have color profiles, wouldn't that mean colors are never outside of “device gamut”— instead, that the colors are displayed in the ranges of the device gamut themselves?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, every browser casts them to INTs.  Maybe.  If I'm wrong you won't be able to tell the difference anyway.  If it really matters, why not just go take screenshots an open them in photoshop or use an on-screen color meter.  Nobody here is going to have a definitive answer without testing it, and it takes 2 minutes to test... so...

Comment: I was interested in the spec, not the per-browser execution of it.

Comment: Then you should have said so ___FIVE YEARS AGO___

Answer (score -1):

I wouldn't know exactly, but it makes sense to just put in some floating numbers and see if it works? it takes two seconds to try with a decimal, and without..

Comment: If I was just building a web page, sure. But this question was asked because I was designing and building a system that had to try to go down the correct route in terms of storing and handling these values.